# NLog | AllowDbNull = true is not logging Info items and just Errors

Tags: database, asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using NLog to log errors/info to the database and file system

When I set `allowDbNull = true` it logs the necessary items as null, but it will not log any `"Info"` records and only trace=error items.

If I remove the `allowDbNull` property then it logs errors/info records BUT puts empty strings instead of nulls for the records that are info.

```
      <parameter name="@EventDateTime" layout="${date}" dbtype="DateTime" />
      <parameter name="@EventLevel" layout="${level}" />
      <parameter name="@UserName" layout="${environment-user}" />
      <parameter name="@MachineName" layout="${machinename}" />
      <parameter name="@EventMessage" layout="${message}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorMessage" layout="${exception:format=message}"  />
      <parameter name="@ErrorType" layout="${exception:format=type}"  />
      <parameter name="@ErrorSource" layout="${exception:format=source}" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorStackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stacktrace}" />
      <parameter name="@InnerErrorMessage" layout="${exception:format=type,message,method,source,stacktrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method,source,stacktrace}"  />
      <!--<parameter name="@ErrorMessage" layout="${exception:format=message}" allowDbNull="true" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorType" layout="${exception:format=type}" allowDbNull="true" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorSource" layout="${exception:format=source}" allowDbNull="true" />
      <parameter name="@ErrorStackTrace" layout="${exception:format=stacktrace}" allowDbNull="true" />
      <parameter name="@InnerErrorMessage" layout="${exception:format=type,message,method,source,stacktrace:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5:innerFormat=shortType,message,method,source,stacktrace}" allowDbNull="true" />-->
```

Comment: Have you tried to enable https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging and look for clues ? (Check if the Logger will output to the expected target at info-level. Check if the database rejects the insert because single table-column does not allow null-values).

Comment: Sounds like you database table won't accept null